# Get data from web server Using Cordova HTTP

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I want to get data from server using post method. In my cordova application I am using this [Cordova HTTP plugin](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP). But I really not understand that tutorial. I want to send email id & password in header and get data from server for this I am using following code.

```
cordovaHTTP.post("https://google.com/", {
    id: 12,
    message: "test"
},{ Authorization: "OAuth2: token" }, function(response) {
    // prints 200
    console.log(response.status);
    try {response.data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        // prints test
        console.log(response.data.message);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error("JSON parsing error");
    }}, function(response) {
    // prints 403
    console.log(response.status);
    //prints Permission denied 
    console.log(response.error);
});
```

Please modify above code and use demo variable for understand.

Answer (score 1):

You ***do*** realise in this code you are posting to google. a `post` is a client server "event" you are (here) the client. but your "server" is google and that is not gonna work because google main home page is going to get a message saying id=12&message=test and google is gonna just go whaaaaaaaaaaaaaa and send you nothing of use - certainly not a usable json string (which this code needs)